# How to Bundle Dependencies with macOS Swift Application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, metasploit

I am working on creating a Swift app for macOS Sierra. I would like to include an installation of Metasploit framework with my app. Installing this to macOS puts files in a few directories like /opt/.

How can I install bundle Metasploit with my app in such a way that it functions like a normal installation on macOS? I thought I could use App Sandbox to mimic /opt/ or other locations for my app. Is something like that possible? I also mentioned this issue here: [Portable Metasploit Installation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174131/portable-metasploit-installation) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The App Sandbox has no API, AFAICT, and it can't be used to make one filesystem location act like another.  Is there a reason you can't just run your dependency directly from the bundle?

Comment: I could include the command in the app bundle, but it expects its own dependencies to be a a particular location on the system, and I want to be able to provide it its own dependencies so that it will work as expected without requiring the user install anything.

Comment: It sounds like you have conflicting requirements, then: a program which requires a particular filesystem layout, in an application bundle that the user can move and run from anywhere.

Comment: Where do you see that it expects its own dependency to be in a particular location?  In the [Metasploit setup](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Setting-Up-a-Metasploit-Development-Environment), it uses a non-root user on Debian, and the only thing it even uses `sudo` for are some library dependencies (through the package manager), and Postgres.